# Symfony 3.2 Crash with Error 'vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php on line 91'

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm not sure why, but when I view one page from my symfony application, it crashes with this error: Symfony 3.2 Crash with Error 'vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php on line 91'. It's not really a complicated page, and it's worked fine previously.

The controller:

```
    public function showAction($motorId)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $motor = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:motors')
        ->findOneBy(['id' => $motorId]);

    if (!$motor) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('motor not found');
    }
    $motorImage = $motor->getImageName();

    return $this->render('motors/motorView.html.twig', array(
        'm' => $motor,
        'image' => $motorImage
    ));

}
```

The twig template:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}

    <div class="row">
        <!-- Motors -->
        {% if m.make is not empty %}
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h3>Motor</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>Make: {{ m.make }}</li>
                    <li>HP: {{ m.hp }}</li>
                    <li>Year: {{ m.year }}</li>
                    <li>Model: {{ m.model }}</li>
                    <li>Serial: {{ m.serial }}</li>
                    <li>Cycle: {{ m.cycle }}</li>
                    <li>Shaft Length: {{ m.shaft }}</li>
                    <li>Condition: {{ m.motorCondition }}</li>
                    <li>Category: {{ m.motorCategory }}</li>
                    <li>Rotation: {{ m.rotation }}</li>
                    <li>Compression: {{ m.compression }}</li>
                    <li>Owner: {{ m.owner }}</li>
                    <li>On Boat: {{ m.onBoat }}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                {% if m.customer %}
                    <h3>Purchase Details</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Name: {{ m.customer.name }}</li>
                        <li>Phone: {{ m.customer.phone1 }}</li>
                        <li>Address: {{ m.customer.address1 }}</li>
                        <li>City: {{ m.customer.city }}</li>
                        <li>State: {{ m.customer.state }}</li>
                        <li>Zip: {{ m.customer.zip }}</li>
                        {#
                        <li>Purchase Price: {{ m.tpurchasePrice }}</li>
                        <li>Date Acquired: {{ m.tDateAcquired|date('m/d/y h:ia') }}</li>
                        #}
                    </ul>
                {% endif %}
            </div>

        {% endif %}
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <a href="{{ path('motor_list') }}" >Back to List</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <a href="{{ path('edit_motor', {'id': m.id}) }}">Edit</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    {#
    {% if image is not empty %}
        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg" >
            <img src="{{ asset('upload/motors/' ~ image) }}" style="max-height: 150px; border: 1px solid;"></img>
        </a>
    {% endif %}
    #}

{% endblock %}
```

Interestingly enough, it's only the one item that causes the issue. Here's the dump information:

```
    motors {#1860 ▼
  -id: 10
  -make: "Yamaha"
  -hp: "250"
  -year: "2012"
  -model: "f250txr"
  -serial: "yamahaserial123"
  -cycle: "4"
  -motorCondition: "Like New"
  -motorCategory: "Outboard"
  -details: null
  -shaft: "25"
  -rotation: "Standard"
  -compression: "180, 180, 180, 180, 180, 180"
  -price: null
  -owner: "Banana Monster"
  -customer: customers {#1936 ▶}
  -createdBy: "keyboard smasher"
  -purchasePrice: "5000"
  -dateAcquired: DateTime {#1856 ▼
    +"date": "2017-06-01 00:00:00.000000"
    +"timezone_type": 3
    +"timezone": "America/New_York"
  }
  -mStatus: null
  -imageFile: null
  -imageName: null
  -updatedAt: DateTime {#1857 ▶}
  -onBoat: 0
  -boat: PersistentCollection {#1928 ▶}
  -saleItem: PersistentCollection {#2000 ▶}
  -boats: null
```

Here's another that works for comparison:

```
 motors {#573 ▼
  -id: 5
  -make: "Yamaha"
  -hp: "250"
  -year: "2005"
  -model: "F250TXR"
  -serial: "YMS102RL192"
  -cycle: "4"
  -motorCondition: null
  -motorCategory: "Outboard"
  -details: null
  -shaft: "25"
  -rotation: null
  -compression: null
  -price: null
  -owner: "Banana Bandit"
  -customer: null
  -createdBy: "keyboard smasher"
  -purchasePrice: null
  -dateAcquired: null
  -mStatus: null
  -imageFile: null
  -imageName: null
  -updatedAt: DateTime {#570 ▶}
  -onBoat: 0
  -boat: PersistentCollection {#582 ▶}
  -saleItem: PersistentCollection {#703 ▶}
  -boats: null
```

Any ideas what would make this one particular item have such a fit?

Comment: is your customer entity called 'customers' ?

Comment: @SamJanssens yes it is

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$motor = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:motors')
        ->find($motorId);
```

Instead of this:

```
$motor = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:motors')
        ->findOneBy(['id' => $motorId]);
```